# Kafka configuration: what's the difference between parameter "cleanup.policy" and parameter "log.cleanup.policy"?

Tags: apache-kafka

There are two parameters to config the Kafka cleanup policy.

- `cleanup.policy`
- `log.cleanup.policy`

What's the difference between them?

[image]

### Reference

[Confluent Platform: Topic Configurations](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/configuration/topic-configs.html#cleanup-policy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says "Server Default Property" - `log.cleanup.policy` is a broker setting and is the default for all topics

`cleanup.policy` is a topic setting used for a specific topic

The docs are also wrong (at least, the table). Valid values are `['compact', 'delete', 'compact,delete']` - [KIP-71](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-71%3A+Enable+log+compaction+and+deletion+to+co-exist)

Comment: If we have two brokers and apply `log.cleanup.policy` to broker A, what will happen to broker B?

Comment: I'd guess which ever is the controller. But I'm not sure because I've never configured a cluster incorrectly like that